# String subscipt out of range

Tags: c++, string, assertion

My code, after being compiled in MS VS 2012, accepts input as it should, and then crashes with the following report:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
...\include\xstring
Line:1662
Expression:string subscript out of range
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;


const unsigned short MAX_STRINGS = 10;
const unsigned int  MAX_SIZE=10000;
vector<string> strings;
unsigned int len;

string GetLongestCommonSubstring( string string1, string string2 );
inline void readNumberSubstrings();
inline const string getMaxSubstring();

void readNumberSubstrings()
{
    cin >> len;

    assert(len > 1 && len <=MAX_STRINGS);

    strings.resize(len);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<len;i++)
        strings[i]=string(MAX_SIZE,0);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<len; i++)
        cin>>strings[i];
}

 const string getMaxSubstring()
{
    string maxSubstring=strings[0];
    long T=clock();
    for(unsigned int i=1; i < len; i++)
        maxSubstring=GetLongestCommonSubstring(maxSubstring, strings[i]);
    cout << clock()-T << endl;
    return maxSubstring;
}

string GetLongestCommonSubstring( string string1, string string2 ) 
{

    const int solution_size = string2.length()+ 1;

    int *x=new int[solution_size]();
    int *y= new int[solution_size]();

    int **previous = &x;
    int **current = &y;

    unsigned int max_length = 0;
    unsigned int result_index = 0;

    unsigned int j;
    unsigned int length;
    int J=string2.length() - 1;

    for(unsigned int i = string1.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(j = J; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            if(string1[i] != string2[j]) 
                (*current)[j] = 0;
            else 
            {
                length = 1 + (*previous)[j + 1];
                if (length > max_length)
                {
                    max_length = length;
                    result_index = i;
                }

                (*current)[j] = length;
            }
        }

        swap(previous, current);
    }
    string1[max_length+result_index]='\0';
    return &(string1[result_index]);
}

int main()
{
    readNumberSubstrings();
    cout << getMaxSubstring() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I guess it must be something really simple (like some loop condition or something like that) that causes it to crash, but I fail to see it.

Comment: Where exactly does it crash?

Comment: And what is your typical input before crash?

Comment: I build it, compile it, run it, enter the number of strings, enter the strings themselves, and then it crashes.

Comment: I enter specific strings that I know should produce a certain result: e.g., I write 3 and then null1, null2,3null and expect to see  "null", but it doesn't get that far

Comment: @Dave, this line is irrelevant, it's a line in `<string>` where it tries to access the out-of-bonds element.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, precisely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is in using `unsigned int`. Look at this line:

```
for(j = J; j >= 0; j--)
```

Here, after j becomes 0, it gets decremented. But your `j` is `unsigned`, so instead of becoming `-1` (and exiting the cycle on the next iteration), `j` becomes `4158584613`, and the cycle continues, trying to access the obviously out-of-bonds element at index `4158584613` at this line:

```
(*current)[j] = 0;
```

Making `i`, `j`, and `length` signed will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something obvious :-)

Answer (score 0):

I loaded it into test solution on my local Visual Studio 2008 and replaced unsigned int with int in i and j and it ran

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;


const unsigned short MAX_STRINGS = 10;
const unsigned int  MAX_SIZE=10000;
vector<string> strings;
unsigned int len;

string GetLongestCommonSubstring( string string1, string string2 );
inline void readNumberSubstrings();
inline const string getMaxSubstring();

void readNumberSubstrings()
{
    cin >> len;

    assert(len > 1 && len <=MAX_STRINGS);

    strings.resize(len);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<len;i++)
        strings[i]=string(MAX_SIZE,0);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<len; i++)
        cin>>strings[i];
}

 const string getMaxSubstring()
{
    string maxSubstring=strings[0];
    long T=clock();
    for(unsigned int i=1; i < len; i++)
        maxSubstring=GetLongestCommonSubstring(maxSubstring, strings[i]);
    cout << clock()-T << endl;
    return maxSubstring;
}

string GetLongestCommonSubstring( string string1, string string2 ) 
{

    const int solution_size = string2.length()+ 1;

    int *x=new int[solution_size]();
    int *y= new int[solution_size]();

    int **previous = &x;
    int **current = &y;

    unsigned int max_length = 0;
    unsigned int result_index = 0;

    int j;
    unsigned int length;
    int J=string2.length() - 1;

    for(int i = string1.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(j = J; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            if(string1[i] != string2[j]) 
                (*current)[j] = 0;
            else 
            {
                length = 1 + (*previous)[j + 1];
                if (length > max_length)
                {
                    max_length = length;
                    result_index = i;
                }

                (*current)[j] = length;
            }
        }

        swap(previous, current);
    }
    string1[max_length+result_index]='\0';
    return &(string1[result_index]);
}

int main()
{
    readNumberSubstrings();
    cout << getMaxSubstring() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks
Niraj Rathi