# Debug assertion failed with unknown reasons

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-debugging, assertion

I get a « Debug Assertion Failed! » (DAF) error related to:

*File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring

Line: 1441
Expression: string subscript out of range*

If I click on the button « Ignore » of the DAF error dialog, the code continues in the correct way, as nothing has happened, so the error should not be in my code...

What can be the cause(s) of this DAF error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888280/string-subscipt-out-of-range seems to suggest that it might be a problem with your code...

Comment: Hmm, thank you but actually it happens when I call the method of a third-party library... I have contacted the developers of the library, and they told me that the method causing the error simply returns the value of a class attribute... I don't have access to the original source code... Is it possible to debug somehow (step-by-step) the xstring code mentioned in the DAF error message?